# Using Django generic CreateView with field editable=False

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm using a url scheme similar to `/foo/1/bar/create` where I'm creating a `Bar` object that has a foreign key to an existing `Foo` object with an id of 1.  I've made the foreign key field back to `Foo` within `Bar` with `editable=False`.

The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) give some general advise on dealing with fields `editable=False`, or fields you've excluded from the form but that are required on the `save()`, but not any advice specific to using the generic `CreateView`.

My `CreateBarView` already gets the `Foo` id via the url and hence it is already in the view's `self.kwargs`.  I'm trying to embrace the generic views to keep things DRY.

Is there a straight forward way of doing this in Django's Generic Views?  Particularly without having to subclass the form?

Note: overriding `get_initial()` doesn't work, and I believe the docs support that.

edit: Django 1.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading over the Django Generic Views, it looks like overriding `get_form()` via `get_form_kwargs` might be the most straightforward if I follow the general [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method), e.g.,

```
class FormMixin(...): # from django.views.generic.edit

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):                                        
        """                                                                     
        Returns an instance of the form to be used in this view.                
        """                                                                     
        if form_class is None:                                                  
            form_class = self.get_form_class()                                  
        return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
```

So,

```
class CreateBarView(...):

   def get_form_kwargs(self):
      kwargs = super(CreateBarView, self).get_form_kwargs()
      kwargs['instance'] = Bar(foo_id=self.kwargs['foo_id'])
      return kwargs
```